# GY-521 module / MPU-6050 3x Accelerometer not detected by i2cdetect

Tags: raspbian, i2c, pi-zero, mpu6050

I got this GY-521 module (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MPU-6050-3-Axis-gyroscope-acce-lerometer-module-3V-5V-compatible-For-Arduino/2035920870.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.pRpLS4) and no matter what i try i cannot get my Raspberry Pi zero/3 to recognize it.

I connected the module as follows:

[image]

```
Module -> Pi
VCC ->  5v/3.3v (tried both options)
GND -> GND
SDA -> SDA
SCL -> SCL
ADD -> GND/3.3v (tried both and without connecting ADD at all)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

And from what i understand, i2c is installed and running fine:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/i2c*
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 0 May 13 16:49 /dev/i2c-0
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 1 May 13 16:49 /dev/i2c-1
```

but when i try to run `i2cdetect -y 1` all i get is an empty table (table of dashes) instead of seeing my module on address 68 or 69.

As soon as i connect the module, its green led lights up so i guess it gets its power but i cannot understand what i can do to make my pi recognize it :(

Comment: Everything you describe sounds correct.  Could you add a photo clearly showing the connections between the Pi and the unit?  We need to be able to trace from the Pi pins to named pins on the I2C module.

Comment: Can you look here and tell me if its ok or should i take more photos?
http://imgur.com/a/KAlMu

Comment: They look fine.

Comment: i read somewhere about chainging some pins from high to low or something like that.. someone with what appears to be the same chip as mine got it solved by that apparently, do you by any chance have any idea what it means?

Comment: I'd power from 3V3 rather than 5V (white wire).  I'd connect ADO to ground rather than 3V3 (orange wire).  If that doesn't work I'd check the jumper wires for continuity.

Comment: One thing jumps out at me - you are not using pull-ups on your I2C.

Comment: @SDsolar from what i understood the SDA and SCL pins of the pi are using internal pullups? maybe i need to enable it somehow?

Comment: The Pi pins 3/5 have hard-wired 1k8 ohm pull-ups to 3V3 specifically for I2C.  If you look closely you will see them next to the pins.  Like all GPIO they also have internal weak (50k) pull-ups/downs which can be enabled in software, but they are irrelevant here.

Comment: thanks @joan i will try to connect it as you suggested tonight and report back...

Comment: In all cases, I defer to @joan.  She has more experience than anybody  else I know of.  Nice to see your name, Joan.

Comment: @joan i tried connecting as you suggested but it still wont get an address.. i ordered another one of these boards and ill try it again when it arrives.. hope i just got a faulty one.

Comment: Some mpu-6050 boards have a built in voltage regulator and require 5v for power and i2c, I had to use it just with my Arduinos and bought another

Comment: @linuxgnuru i tried to connect the vcc to 5v as well as 3.3v.. in both cases it never got an address when i did i2cdetect

Comment: The trouble with using +5V is that the logic levels with that supply voltage may not be reachable by the +3.3V GPIO pins that the RPi uses - IIRC I2C uses open-collector transistor logic so that the output signals from the module _may_ be OK (at least not going to destroy the RPi pins) if it does not have it's __own +5V pull-ups built-in__ but the high output level from the RPi may be being clamped by it's protection diode to go no higher than 4.0 volts or so (but possibly disrupting the operation) even though that is probably enough for the _module_ to recognise it as a logic high level!

Comment: .., if the board DOES have pull-ups - you may benefit from a bi-directional I2C 3.3/5.0V level shifter.

Comment: if you have an [arduino](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050) lying around it might help to [verify](http://42bots.com/tutorials/arduino-uno-and-the-invensense-mpu-6050-6dof-imu/) you don't have a dud piece

Comment: I had an i2c module where 1 pin of the SMD chip was not soldered properly. Check with microscope and if so, ask Aliexpress new board. Also order some other cheap i2c modules to check if they respond.

Answer (score 0):

To get a similar Adafruit ADXL345 working on a Pi Zero, do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

add the lines:

```
i2c-bcm2708
i2c-dev
```

save and exit. Also,

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and enable I2C.

```
sudo reboot
```

(you need to reboot to load the new modules you just added to /etc/modules). After this, running

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

returns a value in the table. To use with python3, add the libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-smbus i2c-tools
```

After this, python3 should also 'see' the accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the accelerometer with an Arduino UNO. If it does not work with an Arduino either, I think the module is faulty.